Unable to send email using SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.(CI version 4.5.3)
I am getting an error when I try to send mail using the codeigniter email service(using CI version 4.5.3). I have used the same email configuration for successfully sending emails with previous versions of Codeigniter 4.
The error says: Unable to send email using SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
My controller code is as follows:
class SendEmail extends BaseController {
    public function index() {
        $recipient = "mytest@gmail.com";
        $subject = "Test Mail";
        $message = "<p>Hi,This is a test mail.</p>";
        
        $email = service('email');
        $email->setFrom("mytest@live.com");
        $email->setTo($recipient);
        $email->setSubject($subject);
        $email->setMessage($message);

        if($email->send()) {
            echo "Email sent successfully";
        }
        else {
            $data = $email->printDebugger(['headers']);
            print_r($data);
            echo "Email sending failed";
        }
    }
}

My .env file :
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# ENVIRONMENT
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

CI_ENVIRONMENT = development

Can anyone please help with this?

Are you using sendmail or google smtp or other service?

I tried smtp with host: smtp-mail.outlook.com

Where is your username, password, port, protocol etc configuration? https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#setting-email-preferences-in-a-config-file:~:text=SMTP%20Server%20Hostname.-,SMTPUser,-No%20Default

To add to this, please post the whole email error message.
